# Compilation of Hadoop Java program with additional dependencies

Tags: java, hadoop, dependencies, apache-commons

I'm attempting to build a Hadoop program, the purpose of which is to `cat` files that I've previously uploaded to HDFS, based largely on [this tutorial](http://hadooptutorial.info/java-interface-to-hdfs-file-read-write/), the program looks like this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URI;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;

public class ReadHDFS {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String uri = args[0];

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri), conf);
        FSDataInputStream in = null ;

        try
        {
            in = fs.open(new Path(uri));
            IOUtils.copyBytes(in, System.out, 4096, false);
        }
        finally
        {
            IOUtils.closeStream(in);
        }   
    }
}
```

It seems to me that the tutorial is flawed, because- *according to my understanding*- IOUtils is part of the `apache.commons` library. However, although I added the following line to the program I've been trying to deploy:

```
import org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils;
```

I'm still met with the following error:

[image]

That is:

```
FileSystemCat.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
        IOUtils.copyBytes(in, System.out, 4096, false);
               ^
  symbol:   method copyBytes(InputStream,PrintStream,int,boolean)
  location: class IOUtils
FileSystemCat.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
        IOUtils.closeStream(in);
                            ^
  symbol:   variable in
  location: class FileSystemCat
2 errors
```

I'm executing it on the NameNode with this command:

```
javac -cp /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.8.1.jar:/home/ubuntu/job_program/commons-io-2.5/commons-io-2.5.jar FileSystemCat.java
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necessary appendix to `~/.bashrc`:

```
# Classpath for Java

# export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$($HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop classpath)
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$($HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop classpath)
```

How to compule the program at the bottom:

```
javac -cp ${HADOOP_CLASSPATH}:commons-io-2.5.jar ReaderHDFS.java
```

How to generate the jar file for that program:

```
jar cf rhdfs.jar ReaderHDFS*.class
```

Run the command:

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar rhdfs.jar ReaderHDFS hdfs://master:9000/input_1/codes.txt
```

This is the program:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils;
//import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URI;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;

public class ReaderHDFS {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String uri = args[0];

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri), conf);
        FSDataInputStream in = null ;

        try
        {
            in = fs.open(new Path(uri));
            IOUtils.copyBytes(in, System.out, 4096, false);
        }
        finally
        {
            IOUtils.closeStream(in);
        }   
    }
}
```